# не работают слеш команды на серверах в лс с ботом работают в discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

PREFIX = ''
intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.message_content = True

test_guilds = [1120440318643425492]
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents, guilds=test_guilds)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot ready for work!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'Synced {len(synced)} command(s)')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.tree.command(name='hello')
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Hey! :){interaction.user.mention}! This is a slash command!', ephemeral=True)

@bot.tree.command(name='say')
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say='what should i say?')
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} said: `{thing_to_say}`')

bot.run('Тут токен')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Вместо этого вы можете использовать bot.application_commands для синхронизации ваших команд.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

...

@bot.slash_command(name='hello')
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Hey! {interaction.user.mention}! This is a slash command!', ephemeral=True)

@bot.slash_command(name='say')
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} said: `{thing_to_say}`')

...
```

Comment: Метод **bot.tree.sync()** как раз таки и существует. Декоратор describe более чем там - допустим. Лучше изучите библиотеку, прежде чем отвечать.